# How to use colorbox in window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, colorbox

i have this popup function using javascript

```
 function BookingIDCancellation() {

        window.open("popup/BookingIDCancellation.aspx?field=BookingID|<%=txtBookingID.clientid%>", "mywindow", "menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=450")

    }
```

i use this function on button so that it will popup after clicking on it and get value from the popup page.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBrowse" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Browse" OnClientClick="BookingIDCancellation();return false;" />
```

How to use this window.open with jquery colorbox so that the popup window will look nicer?

Comment: try onload event.You can also call your colorbox using  jquery. $(document).ready(function(){...here});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
function BookingIDCancellation(){
     $.colorbox({href:"popup/BookingIDCancellation.aspx?field=BookingID|<%=txtBookingID.clientid%>", width:"500px", height:"450px"});
}
```

Please note that if "BookingIDCancellation.aspx" contains Postback functions you need to add the "iframe:true" paramater to the $.colorbox function, and you need to set the Postback URL in the "BookingIDCancellation.aspx" page.

iFrame code:

```
function BookingIDCancellation(){
     $.colorbox({href:"popup/BookingIDCancellation.aspx?field=BookingID|<%=txtBookingID.clientid%>", width:"500px", height:"450px", iframe:true});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but actually this function can only pass the parameter to BookingIDCancellation.aspx. but it failed to send the bookingID value from BookingIDCancellation.aspx to the parent page. how can i fix it?

Comment: I understand that you're using document.opener to return the value from the popup, Am I am correct?

Comment: i use this opener.document.getElementById('BookingID').value="something".